# Google Analytics event doesn't show up as conversion

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I'm trying to implement event tracking in Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager. At the moment I can see the event being triggered in the real time report, but it doesn't show up under conversions.

These are the Tag Manager settings:

[image: tag manager settings]

And the Analytics configuration:

[image: analytics event]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a GTM variable (in label field) inside Google Analytics. You can't use {{NLNL formID}} in Google Analytics when setting up the objective.

In order to work you must choose in label field, "Regular expression" instead of "Equal to" and use only "Form:" instead of the GTM variable.

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear, please, select the answer as correct to help other users. Regards.